# An extension for PHP to highlight never-written read-used variables?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Do you know a VSCode extension for PHP that would highlight variable that I'd access in read but that were never initialized?

It would be useful for example in this scenario: I write a function `A`, then I find it too long so I take a portion of `A` and I move this portion inside a new function `B` that is called within `A`. The extension would be useful to be sure that `B` doesn't contain variables access in read that were declared in `A`.

Answer (score 0):

[php intelephense](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense) does this.
I have the Premium variant installed. I've purchased it a few years ago; don't know if reg-status follows along when I sync VSCode settings over many computers.
So I don't know precisely what the free version does.

If you defined temporary variables in the body of a class method, intelephense will do this (see comments):

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $test1;  //  intelephense will highlightt in red as  error: Undefined Variable '$test'
    $test2 = null;  //  intelephense will grey this out

    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    {
      //  do something
    }
}
```